# A java Program which take input from 1 to 9 and print all odd from left to right then print even from right to left

Tags: java, arrays

> **I want only one loop to archive this output**

input={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}  output={1,3,5,7,9,8,6,4,2}

```
    public static void printOddEven(int[] arr) {
    int newArray[] = new int[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 != 0) {
            newArray[i] = arr[i];
            System.out.print(newArray[i] + " ");
        }
    }
    for (int i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
            newArray[i] = arr[i];
            System.out.print(newArray[i] + " ");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: *I want only one loop to archive this output* Okay. Well the code you posted has two. Does it work? You've told us what you want, but you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: how about starting from the end and appending the odd numbers at the head and the even numbers at the tail?

Comment: if i is less than 5, print 1 + i*2. Else print 8 - (i - 5)*2

Comment: Ofcourse if input could be anything else, you have to first calculate what in previous case turned out to be 1, 8, and 5.

Comment: This is a typical example of something for which the point is for you to figure it out yourself (by looking at what you want to have happen for each i). Having someone else give you the answer will give you the answer, but won't help much for the next problem you try to tackle (since you side-stepped the whole process of attempting to solve it).

Comment: Is printing in the loop necessary? Is it the main goal? Is the main goal filling of the new Array? Why do you use an array size of 10 for 9 elements? Why arrays at all?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an array:

```
int [] result = new int[arr.length];
int counterFront = 0;
int counterBack = arr.length - 1;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 != 0) {
            result[counterFront++] = arr[i];
        }

        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
            result[counterBack--] = arr[i];
        }
 }
return result;
```

EDIT: Thanks to a comment, found out it had a ArrayIndexOutOfBounds.

Comment: `if (arr[i] % 2 == 0 && i >= arr.length) {  newArray[i] = arr[i]; ...` index out of bounds exception incoming

Answer (score 1):

```
int newArray[] = new int[9];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 != 0) 
        newArray[i/2] = arr[i];
    else 
        newArray[8-(i/2)] =  arr[i];
 }

 System.out.println (java.util.Arrays.toString (newArray));
```

Just use a descendant index from the right 
Why do you use Arrays at all? Is it homework? Note that you get an off-by-one-error, because your newArray is too large, when using int[10] for 9 elements, a typical problem with Arrays.

Comment: You still need a second loop to print the content of `newArray`

Comment: I understand `output` not  literally, but as *achieve the output, the result', since the question continues with two arrays in Java source notation, and there are no curly braces in the example with two loops.

Comment: What about the word `print` in the title?

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino: Better?

Comment: No, that' cheating. The question asks how to map input at index to output at same index. Yours and others solutions say how to map input at index to output at different index.

Comment: IMHO the emphasize is on the one loop and how to fill a new array in the right order. As long as the asking user doesn't clarify the question, this is just your interpretation. You might be right, but I don't think so. I think he and you didn't mention, that his newArray is the same as arr, except for the trailing 0, because what could be the purpose of it?

Comment: @userunknown I believe this is a correct interpretation of OP's requirement. Upvote.

Comment: @MiljenMikic: Well, thanks. I wish Coderinos solution wan't correct, so I could downvote his approach, but I'm not even sure whether he downvoted me, nor am I a fan of revenge voting. But I upvoted the other working solutions. Except of his, because it doesn't fill the newArray, and another one, which fills two arrays, and a third one, which produces an AIOOBE. :)

Comment: @userunknown FYI you can downvote whatever you want. Go ahead, I won't mind, if that'll make you feel better

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino: I can't, because your solution is not bad enough. :) It doesn't depend on whether you mind or not, but what I think is right or wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon this is more of a maths problem than a programming problem. It's about knowing there is a simple arithmetic relationship between an incrementing index and a decrementing index.

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

public static void printOddEven(int[] arr) {
    int[] odds = new int[5];  // arr.length == 9
    int[] even = new int[4];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
            // This is where the magic happens
            // It is filling the array from the back
            even[even.length - (i / 2) - 1] = arr[i];
        } else {
            odds[(i / 2)] = arr[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(odds));
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(even));
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

Just for @CoderinoJavarino, here is a version where the output is a single array. The core logic and maths is identical, so take your pick which is easier to understand.

The use of `Arrays.toString()` is *not* there as part of the algorithm solution. It is there simply so that you can *see* the output. I could equally send the output to a file, or to a web socket.

The output is not the printing, the output is the array or arrays. It could equally have been a `List`, or a special class just for sorting odd/even numbers. Who cares?

In industrial programming (ie, non-academic) this is how code gets divided up: for ease of understanding, not cleverness. And in the business world there is no concept of "cheating": Nobody worries about the internals of, say, a JSP, rendering your array to a browser.

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

public static int[] SORTOddEven(int[] arr) {
    int[] output = new int[arr.length];  // arr.length == 9

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) {
            // This is where the magic happens
            // It is filling the array from the back
            output[output.length - (i / 2) - 1] = arr[i];
        } else {
            output[(i / 2)] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return output;
}

System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(SORTOddEven(arr)));
```

Comment: Using `Arrays.toString` is cheating in this context IMO

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino Cheating? The OP wanted sorted output with a single loop. That's what I've supplied, along with some explanation.

Comment: Arrays to string simply hides another loop inside standard lib. Clearly the requirement is to solve, how to map an input at index to an output at the same index directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void printOddEven(int[] arr) {
    int newArray[] = new int[9];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] % 2 != 0)
            newArray[i/2] = arr[i];
        else
            newArray[arr.length - i/2 - 1] = arr[i];                
    }

    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(newArray));    
}
```

[Live on Ideone.](https://ideone.com/LUp6Z8)

Answer (score 0):

This only works for `123456789` to print `135798642`:

```
public class Sample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     int j=0;
     int p=2;
    int newArray[]= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    for(int i=0;i<=newArray.length-1;i++)
    {
        if(i<=4)
        {
            System.out.print(newArray[i]+j);
            j++;

        }
        else
        {
            System.err.print(newArray[i]+p);
            p=p-3;
    }
}

}
}
```

Comment: This throws an AIOOBE for me.

Comment: Sorry,in side for loop (int i=0;i<=newArray.length-1;i++) . you can check now